# MIT-Scheme: Different Behavior on Infinite Loop Depending on Numbers

Tags: scheme, sicp, mit-scheme

I was working on the solution of the exercise 1.6 of the SICP book when I saw two different behaviors when I run the code depending on the numbers that I used.

If I use natural numbers when I call the sqrt-iter procedure the interpreter just never stop but when I force the decimal division using float-point numbers the interpreter responds: Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Does anyone know the reason for the different behavior?

I made a gist with my answer to help anyone that wants to run the code, just copy & paste: http://bit.ly/Qv1wru. The mit-scheme version is 9.1.1.

Comment: You might want to tell us *what two numbers you used*. Also, consider looking at a solution from Bill the Lizard http://www.billthelizard.com/2009/10/sicp-exercises-16-18.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `good-enough?` procedure seems wrong, try with this one:

```
(define (good-enough? guess x)
  (< (abs (- (sqr guess) x)) 0.001))
```

Comment: Thanks Óscar i tested my code with your version of good-enough? procedure but the behavior is the same. I mean, the expected behavior is the infinite loop, that is part of the exercise. In fact the good-enough? procedure is never called. My cuestion is about the different responds that the interpreter give you when you use rational numbers or when you force the decimal division using decimal numbers. I wrote a note in my gist to point that.